# Error 1004 when attempting to save as PDF via macro in Excel on network drive

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies in advance, as I am very new to this and finding this a very steep learning curve!

I have an Excel document that is used by myself and colleagues, and have a macro button to save this as a PDF document. The PDF needs to be saved in a folder on a network drive, in a year folder then a month folder.

I have some code which works great for me. I creates a new year folder if it doesn't exist, creates a month folder if it doesn't exist, then saves the PDF in this folder.

However, this only works for me.

When a colleague attempts to do this on their computer, Excel creates the folders but does not save the PDF, giving a run-time error 1004.

I have attempted to change bits and pieces in the code, and nothing seems to work, so I am in a bit of a position really.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
    Sub Save_ActSht_as_Pdf()
    ' Saves active sheet as PDF file.
    Const basePath = "I:\folder path\"
    If Dir(basePath & Year(Date), vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir basePath & Year(Date)
    If Dir(basePath & Format(Date, "yyyy\\mmmm yy"), vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir basePath & Format(Date, "yyyy\\mmmm yy")
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Format(Now, "yyyy\\mmmm yy\\ddd MMMM d yyyy AM/PM"), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

(I have substituted the actual folder path for 'folder path' for ease)

The line that is highlighted during a debug is the one starting with ActiveSheet

Thank you in advance for any help with this problem.

Comment: A file name can't contain a backslash. And are you missing basePath from that line?  Maybe works for you if that's your current directory, but may not work for others if they don't have that set as their current directory.  Always best to provide full paths.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for the quick reply. I had taken out the AM/PM and it makes no difference. I didn't notice the basePath, will amend that and give it a go. I will let you know the results :)

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for your help with that - I added basePath in and it works. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
Option Explicit

   Sub Save_ActSht_as_Pdf()
    ' Saves active sheet as PDF file.
    Const basePath = "C:\folder path\"
    Dim fn As String
    If Dir(basePath & Year(Date), vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir basePath & Year(Date)
    If Dir(basePath & Format(Date, "yyyy\\mmmm yy"), vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir basePath & Format(Date, "yyyy\\mmmm yy")
    fn = basePath & Format(Now, "yyyy\\mmmm yy\\ddd MMMM d yyyy AM/PM") & ".pdf"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:=fn, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

I had to create "folder path" folder manually as MkDir can only create one folder level at once.

Also if the ActiveSheet is empty then runtime error 1004 happens as nothing to print